Can someone translate to me the next phrase?
Super metis etiam provinciae Moldaviae cum provincia Transalpina secundum antiquos terminos et consuetudines per praedecessores Vayvodas possessos et tentos utrumque Vayvodam, tam scilicet Stephanum Moldaviensem, quam Vlad Transalpinum, secundum privilegia Alexandri et Mirczae utriusque partis Vayvodarum concordamus.
My interest resides in the meaning of metis and terminos. I am interested in the medieval terminology for the frontier and border and I want to see what would be the best translation for this. I need to mention that this fragment comes from a 1475 treaty between the voyvode of Moldavia, Stephen the Great and the king of Hungary Mathias Corvinus. I want to know how the hungarian kingdom understood these concepts. Thank you in advance.
